# Two tests for the same question

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size, hypothesis-testing

We have two series of scores (continuous variables) obtained for two groups of students formed randomly from a population for which we ask ourselves whether an intervention (a teaching method for example) is effective or not. The intervention group receives the intervention (index i), the other group constitutes the control group (index c).
Scores are normally distributed, sample sizes are greater than 30, and the variances of the two sets of scores are equal.
To answer the question, I used two methods: a Student t test of the equality of means and a Student t test of the effect size. The two calculated statistics are very close but still different.

Question

It is about this difference that I am wondering because it seems to me that both methods answer the same question, and require the same conditions of use. How then to explain that the results are not exactly the same?

In the following calculations, I use the following notations:
mi: mean of the intervention group scores
ni: number of students in the intervention group
if: standard deviation of intervention group scores
mc: mean of the scores of the control group
nc: number of students in the control group
sc: standard deviation of the scores of the control group.

I calculate a grouped standard deviation S to estimate the standard deviation of the population
S² = [(ni-1) * si² + (nc-1) * sc²] / (ni + nc-2)

Method 1. t-test for the difference of means

Null hypothesis: the difference of the means of the two populations is equal to zero.
We calculate the statistic t.

t1 = (mi-mc) / [S * (1 / ni + 1 / nc) ^ 0.5]

We conclude by comparing t1 with the critical statistic with ni + nc-2 as a degree of freedom and we calculate the associated p-value.

Method 2. Calculation of the effect size.

I used Cohen’s d (Hedges’s g involves a multiplicative coefficient that would not change the results because the sample sizes are greater than 30).

d = (mi-mc) / S

We calculate the variance of d.

var (d) = 1 / ni + 1 / nc + d² / [2 * (ni + nc)]

We calculate the standard error of d.

s (d) = var (d) ^ 0.5

We perform a t test.

Null hypothesis: the effect size of the population is equal to zero.
We calculate the statistic t.

t2 = d / s (d) = (mi-mc) / [S * (1 / ni + 1 / nc + d² / (2 * (ni + nc)) ^ 0.5]

We conclude by comparing t2 with the critical statistic with ni + nc-2 as a degree of freedom and we calculate the associated p-value.

We notice that t1 and t2 are different (t2 <t1).

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct formula for the standard error of d?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure (for example, Borenstein, Introduction to meta analysis, p.27).